# Combining Multiple Fuzzy Joins

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, data-manipulation

Using the R programming language, I have the following two tables (in my actual problem, all dates are given to me in "factor" types):

```
table_1 = data.frame(id1 = c("123 A", "123BB", "12 5", "12--5"), id2 = c("11", "12", "14", "13"),
date_1 = c("2010-01-31","2010-01-31", "2015-01-31", "2018-01-31" ))

table_1$id1 = as.factor(table_1$id1)
table_1$id2 = as.factor(table_1$id2)
table_1$date_1 = as.factor(table_1$date_1)

table_2 = data.frame(id1 = c("0123", "1233", "125  .", "125_"), id2 = c("111", "112", "14", "113"),
date_2 = c("2009-01-31","2010-01-31", "2010-01-31", "2010-01-31" ),
date_3 = c("2011-01-31","2010-01-31", "2020-01-31", "2020-01-31" ))


table_2$id1 = as.factor(table_2$id1)
table_2$id2 = as.factor(table_2$id2)
table_2$date_2 = as.factor(table_2$date_2)
table_2$date_3 = as.factor(table_2$date_3)
```

I am trying to perform an "inner join" if either Condition 1 OR Condition 2 is true:

**Condition_1**

- if table_1$id "fuzzy equal" table_2$id AND
- if table_1$date BETWEEN(table_2$date_2,table_2$date_3)

**Condition_2**

- if table_1$id2 "fuzzy equal" table_2$id2

Right now, I know how to do this in 2 part:

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

part_1 =  stringdist_inner_join(table_1, table_2, by = "id1", max_dist = 2) %>%
  filter(date_1 >= date_2, date_1 <= date_3) 

part_2 =  stringdist_inner_join(table_1, table_2, by = "id2", max_dist = 2) 

combine = rbind(part_1, part_2)

final = combine[!duplicated(combine[c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)]),]
```

**My Question**

- Is there a "better" way to run this join together, instead of in two separate parts?
- It seems that the SQL query in "part_1" is first performing a fuzzy join on **all** records, and then only keeping the relevant records that satisfy the date criteria, i.e. `filter(date_1 >= date_2, date_1 <= date_3)` . This seems to be an inefficient way of doing things - or is this the only way possible to accomplish this task, since a fuzzy join must be run on all rows by default to see if "id" condition is satisfied, and only then the "date" condition can be satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to do this in a loop, loop over the variable part i.e. the `by`

```
library(purrr)
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
final2 <- map_dfr(c("id1", "id2"),  ~
       stringdist_inner_join(table_1, table_2, by = .x, max_dist = 2)) %>%
       distinct %>%
       arrange(across(everything()))
```

-checking

```
> all.equal(final %>% 
         arrange(across(everything())), final2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @ akrun: Thank you so much for your answer! I am still new to the "purrr" library - could you please explain the following two lines of code?

Comment: 1) map_dfr(c("id1", "id2"),  ~

Comment: 2)   arrange(across(everything()))

Comment: Are there any other ways that you could have prepared the answer "final_2"? thank you so much!

Comment: @stats555 1) `map` loops over the vector of `by`, the `_dfr` is to rbind all the list output on the output of join/distinct`,  2) the `arrange` step is to make sure I can check on your original `final` object which had a different row order.  There could be other ways as well

Comment: @ akrun: thank you for your reply! If you have time, can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231544/r-re-writing-fuzzy-join-functions-from-r-to-sql thank you!